# Easy way to get hex from a string in .net

Tags: c#

I want to get hex from a string like this:

```
Color c = new Color();
c.A = Int32.Parse("0x7F");
```

What's the right method for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hex string isn't known till runtime, then something like this:

```
c.A = Convert.ToInt32("0x7F", 16);
```

Or as a literal if the value is known at compile time:

```
    c.A = 0x7F;
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `Parse` method, check the overload which allows `NumberStyles`.  Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c09yxbyt.aspx

```
int bla = Int32.Parse("beef", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt32("hexvaluestring", 16);`
Should be enough.